# How to hide vertical scroll bar in specific div for all browser

Tags: html, css, webkit

```
cssmenu::-webkit-scrollbar{display: none;}
```

I can hide scrollbar for chrome browser by using this code but in other browsers it is still visible.

How can I supress the scrollbar for this specific div in all browsers equaly?

Comment: overflow-y: hidden; ????

Comment: -webkit-,-moz-,-ms-

Answer (score 0):

See the Below Snippet :

```css
#container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"><div id="container2">
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>scrolling</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>Scrolling</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
<div>.....</div>
</div>
</div>
```